# Cross-stack reference within a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Going round in circles and tearing my hair out on this one, any pointers are greatly appreciated.

I have a CloudFormation stack which creates an EC2 instance. I am outputting its ID as follows:

```
 Outputs:
  DevBoxInstanceId:
    Description: The instance ID of the EC2 Dev_Box.
    Value: !Ref TestInstance
    Export: 
      Name: DevBoxId
```

Now, in the console I can see that this outputs the ID as I'd like. My problem is that I can't work out how to reference this in my second stack. I haven't used Fn::ImportValues much but for obvious reasons I'd like to. My second stack creates a lambda function which will stop an instance. I want to reference the DevBoxId within the function - have I misunderstood something here? I've tried several variations on the following:

```
LambdaFunctionStop:
 Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
 Properties: 
  Runtime: python3.7
  Timeout: 30
  Code:
    ZipFile: |
      import boto3
      region = 'eu-west-2'
      instances = ['!ImportValue DevBoxId'] 
      ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

      def handler(event, context):
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
        print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
  Description: Automatically stop Dev_Env instances based on specified schedule.
  Handler: index.handler 
  Role: !GetAtt 'IAMRole.Arn'
```

The relevant part which I'm seeking help on is:

```
instances = ['!ImportValue DevBoxId']
```

How do I write this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your ZipFile component is meant to be a string. So you will need to refer to Export Values outside that string and then substitute the value within that string. Try the below

```
LambdaFunctionStop:
 Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
 Properties: 
  Runtime: python3.7
  Timeout: 30
  Code:
    ZipFile: 
      !Sub
        - |
          import boto3
          region = 'eu-west-2'
          instances =  '${devboxvalue}'
          ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

          def handler(event, context):
           ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
           print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
        - { devboxvalue : !ImportValue "DevBoxId" }
  Description: Automatically stop Dev_Env instances based on specified schedule.
  Handler: index.handler 
  Role: !GetAtt 'IAMRole.Arn'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance id to tha lambda's environment variables this way:
[image]
and you can then access if from you code depending on the way you read env variables